# Is there a smarter solution for querying data from user

Tags: ruby, methods, while-loop

I want to query a player name from the user, if the number of tries exceeded ==> abort.
I made this solution, but I think there's another simpler/smarter way to do it :

```
def queryplayername(displaymessage)
  puts displaymessage
  return gets.chomp.strip
end

def exitforspecificreason(reason)
  puts "Exiting the game for #{reason}"
  exit
end
    
player1name = queryplayername("Enter Player 1's name:")
timesleft = 3
while player1name.empty?
  player1name = queryplayername("Player name can not be empty, please enter valid Player1 name, #{timesleft} times left:")
  timesleft -= 1
  exitforspecificreason('Exiting the game : exceeded number of tries!') if timesleft.zero? && player1name.empty?
end
```

Is there a better solution to replace the while loop using (times/upto/until) ?

Any input is appreciated.

Cheers !

Comment: As a note, Ruby is all about being short, concise, yet expressive. Having method names this convoluted and long does go against the grain. Normally you'd wrap these in a Class, so you could do things like `game.prompt_player_name` or `game.exit`.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of way to do this, but here's where I think you ought to start:

```rb
class Player
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize
    get_name
  end 

  def prompt
    print 'Enter player name: '
    @name = gets.chomp
    STDERR.puts "Name can't be empty." if @name.empty?
  end 

  def get_name
    max_tries = 3 
    1.upto(max_tries) do
      prompt
      return if !@name.empty?
    end 
    raise "exceeded #{max_tries} tries"
  end 
end

class Game
  def initialize
    @player1 = Player.new
  end 
end

game = Game.new
```

This will prompt up to three times, or raise an exception if the number of tries is exceeded:

> `get_name': exceeded 3 tries (RuntimeError)

If you really want to rely on standard output rather than an exception to exit the game, just replace the call to `raise` with whatever method will exit the program (hint: don't call it #exit, as that conflicts with [Kernel#exit](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Kernel.html#method-i-exit)).